# Rendering Markdown to multiple blocks in Jinja2 Template

Tags: python, jinja2, markdown, static-site, pelican

So lets say I have a base template and I want to have two blocks - one named primary and one named secondary.  When I go to write my markdown file, is it possible to render sections of my markdown to both blocks?  I was reading through markdown documentation and Jinja documentation and I didn't really see a clear answer to this as far as I could tell.

Comment: Hey Andrew - welcome to SO! If possible, please can you provide an example (ideally [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) that shows what you're currently trying, and what your desired outcome would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base template that contains as many blocks as you would like, and then define new pages that extend the base template and define the content that should go in those blocks. A simple example:

**base.html**

```
<div>
{% block my_primary_block %}
{% endblock %}
</div>

<div>
{% block my_secondary_block %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Now, supposing you want to populate those blocks from another HTML file, you could define the content of each block:

**article.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block my_primary_block %}
Hello world!
{% endblock %}

{% block my_secondary_block %}
Goodbye world!
{% endblock %}
```

but since you asked about markdown, you can use variables from articles using `{{ article.variable_name }}` from the HTML, and then define `variable_name` in an article header. For example,

**article.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block my_primary_block %}
{{ article.primary }}
{% endblock %}

{% block my_secondary_block %}
{{ article.secondary }}
{% endblock %}
```

then in your article, you just add those fields to the metadata for the article:

**content/my_blog_post.md**

```
Title: My cool blog post
Date: 2000-01-01 00:00
Primary: Hello world!
Secondary: Goodbye world!

This is the content of my cool blog post.
```